# Como mandar a llamar un reporte desde un menuItem en primefaces?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tengo un menubar con varias opciones y dentro de una, o sea en un submenu quiero mandar a llamar un reporte, lo cual ya lo tengo pero se muestra a traves de un boton, y no quiero que sea asi, quiero que al escoger en el submenu en automatico muestre el reporte

este es mi codigo donde tengo el menu

```
<p:menuitem value="Reporte" url="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsf/reporte.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" />
```

y este es el codigo de la pagina que muestra el reporte

```
 <h:form>

         <p:commandButton value="Generar Reporte" update="@form" actionListener="#{SctBienComponent.generateReport}" />
        <div class="column-center">
            <p:media cache="false" rendered="#{SctBienComponent.media ne null}" width="900" height="600" value="#{SctBienComponent.media}" player="pdf"/>
        </div>
```

solo quiero quitar el boton, y que en automatico sin presionar nada, muestre el reporte

Answer (score 0):

El menu item tambien puede ejecutar action como lo hace el boton, ademas del update que es muy util.

```
<p:menuitem value="Reporte" action="#{SctBienComponent.tuaccion}" 
update="@form"/>
```

No me queda muy claro si vas a redireccionar o vas actualizar un componente en la misma pagina, si vas a redireccionar lo puedes realizar con javascript desde el menu item o tambien llamando javascript desde el action en el server.

Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Solo como referencia, mira [tour] y [answer]. Si vas a preguntar mira [ask]. Bienvenido al sitio y gracias por aportar. Podrias aclararle a OP la segunda parte de la respuesta?